# Send email with token to new user to create account in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an application where a user (we will call 'original user') can create a 'plan' and then add other user's to that 'plan' so they can view the 'plan'.  The original user can simply enter the email address of the user they want to add.  If that user already exists, the user will be added to the plan and there are no issues.

In the case that the user does not exist, I am having the original user enter the email address and an initial password for that user.  I can trigger an email to go to the new user to notify them.  The new user is added to the Plan Mapping table so they are attached to that plan.

The vulnerability in my approach is that the original user could start creating accounts for people inappropriately and that the original user has to tell the new user their password or the new user has to hit 'Forgot Password' the first time they log in.

It would be ideal for the original user simply to add an email for the user they want to add to the plan.  If the user exists, the user is added to the plan automatically.  If the user does not exist, they are added to the Plan Mapping somehow and sent an email with a token to create an account.

I know how to send an Activation email.  However, that doesn't work because the password is still created by the original user.  I don't know how I could send an email with that user to sign up and then automatically do the Plan Mapping after that user signs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could create a user without password.
2) When create a signed url for the new user and send it via email. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#signed-urls
3) User will get to the link you have create and will have to enter a new password.

Comment: I think that is the way to go, however, wouldn't that require that I make the password field in my users table nullable?  Is there anyway to do this without making this field nullable and causing other issues in different parts of the app

Comment: @Alexander generate a really long password `Str::random()`

Comment: @Alexander but I think it's not very difficult  for you to modify  the authentication logic check password equals to NULL. Even more you will have the ability to count the user that never been authenticated in your system. Opportunity to resend email later again.